# Setting permanent export EDITOR to nano for all future sessions

Tags: ssh, nano

Every time I SSH into my AWS, I am changing editor to nano. Is there a command to run that will change it to nano for all future instances a well?

Comment: Put it in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Certainly looks like a dupe but the accepted answer in the question you have linked is pretty bad: a simple link to a pretty messy Ubuntu wiki page?

Comment: @andrew.46: Look at the next answer with more than the quadruple amount of votes then. :-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Fair enough :)

Answer (score 13):

A couple of easy steps should see you through:

1. Log into your account using ssh
2. Open the file `~/.bashrc`with a text editor
3. Add something like the following:

   ```
   export EDITOR='/usr/bin/nano'
   ```
4. Save the file (and adjust the path to nano if you have it in a non-standard location)
5. Either log out and back in again or simply type:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

And then you should be set :).

**References:**

- [How to set the default text editor in Linux](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/linux/setting-the-default-text-editor-in-linux)

Answer (score 8):

To set the default editor using the `update-alternatives` command. Open up a terminal window and type in the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

Here’s an example of what you’ll see:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives –config editor

There are 5 alternatives which provide `editor’.

Selection Alternative
———————————————–
1 /usr/bin/vim
2 /bin/ed
*+ 3 /bin/nano
4 /usr/bin/vim.basic
5 /usr/bin/vim.tiny
Press enter to keep the default[*], or type selection number:
```

You can select the editor you want by just typing in the number. For example, if I want to change the default editor to vim, I would just hit the number 1.